# What would be the correct twig naming convention to override a table specific to a view page

Tags: theming

can someone tell me the naming convention for a table in a specific page view please

I have views.view--custom-page.html.twig to over ride the page

I assumed it would be views-view-table--custom-page.html.twig for the table but that doesn't seem to over ride it and I can't find the correct naming convention for this.

Thanks

Comment: Here is a great guide, http://redcrackle.com/blog/drupal-8/theme-views-templates

Comment: Thank you for the response but this still isn't working for me. Reading that tutorial I assumed I just needed views-view-table--custom-page--page-1.html.twig to  override the default but it is not working still, I did Clear the cache several times to be sure. Have I got this wrong for D8.7 I also assumed page-1 is the default for the first page created in the view, if not how would I find this?   my machine name for the view is page_1, I checked

Comment: Have you tried views-view-table—page-1—default.html.twig

Comment: Realised there was a spelling error in my code, views-view-table--custom-page--page-1.html.twig works as expected now I have taken my stupid hat off :) thanks for assisting.